# Is the charge density value in the electromagnetic wave equation necessarily equal to zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

The transmission space of electromagnetic wave is divided into source free and source region. In the case of source region, the current density is not equal to zero because the electromagnetic wave entering the conductor medium is caused by the time-varying electric field, but the time-varying electric field does not generate a net charge, so Is it true that the charge density in the wave equation must be zero in any case?

Answer (score 0):

No. Charged particles can generate electromagnetic waves simply by accelerating, without needing to be part of a current loop which ensures that the charge is zero.

The [Larmor formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula) is a good counterexample along those lines. So is a [dipole antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna).

It's not just that there are counterexamples, it turns out that the whole idea is ridiculous. Relativistically, $(c\rho, \mathbf J)$ is a four-vector and the only four-vector whose time component is zero in all frames of reference is the zero vector. Literally, relativity blocks you from saying that in all cases $\rho =0$ without also saying that in all cases $\mathbf J=0.$ **Every** neutral-looking current loop has a nonzero charge density in some other reference frame.

Comment: So, if an electromagnetic wave is incident on a region with charge and current, should the value of the charge and current in the region be directly put into the equation and solved?